# Wro4j Custom XML Model Location

Tags: wro4j

I've put `wro.xml` in `src/main/resources` as there are some other resources and it's easier to access them in unit tests.

I need to extend some wro classes now to be able to read the model from another place, but can't get it working.

**Necessary code**

web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
        <param-value>wroFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>WebResourceOptimizer</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/resources/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="wroFilter" class="ro.isdc.wro.http.ConfigurableWroFilter">
    <property name="properties" ref="wroProperties" />
</bean>

<bean id="wroProperties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:wro.properties" />
</bean>
```

wro.properties:

```
managerFactoryClassName=com.example.web.wro.manager.factory.MyWroManagerFactory;
preProcessors=cssUrlRewriting,cssImport,semicolonAppender,lessCss
postProcessors=cssMin,jsMin
debug=true
```

MyWroManagerFactory:

```
public class MyWroManagerFactory extends CopyrightKeeperConfigurableWroManagerFactory {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyWroManagerFactory.class);

    @Override
    protected WroModelFactory newModelFactory() {
        LOG.debug("Load wro.xml directly from classpath");
        return new XmlModelFactory() {
            @Override
            protected InputStream getModelResourceAsStream() throws IOException {
                final String resourceLocation = getDefaultModelFilename();
                final InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceLocation);

                if (stream == null) {
                    throw new IOException("Invalid resource requested: " + resourceLocation);
                }

                return stream;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

CopyrightKeeperConfigurableWroManagerFactory:

```
public class CopyrightKeeperConfigurableWroManagerFactory extends ConfigurableWroManagerFactory {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CopyrightKeeperConfigurableWroManagerFactory.class);

    private static final String[] PROCESSORS = {
        CssImportPreProcessor.ALIAS,
        JawrCssMinifierProcessor.ALIAS,
        CssMinProcessor.ALIAS,
        JSMinProcessor.ALIAS
    };

    @Override
    protected void contributePreProcessors(final Map<String, ResourcePreProcessor> map) {
        for (String processor : PROCESSORS) {
            if (map.containsKey(processor)) {
                LOG.debug("Apply CopyrightKeeperProcessorDecorator on " + processor);
                map.put(processor, CopyrightKeeperProcessorDecorator.decorate(map.get(processor)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why it can't find `classes/wro.xml` / How to use a custom location for wro.xml?

**EDIT**
Here's the full log output: http://pastebin.com/NeNy1NH4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading the model relative to the MyWroManagerFactory class:

```
 final InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceLocation);
```

That means that it will look for the model in the folder where the class is located. Since your wro.xml is located in classes folder (which is a root for classpath), you should use the following:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(resourceLocation);
```

Alternatively you could use ClasspathUriLocator:

```
new ClasspathUriLocator().locate("classpath:" + resourceLocation)
```

**EDITED**:
Apparently this example discovered a problem which is described in the following [issue](https://code.google.com/p/wro4j/issues/detail?id=736):
Until the fix is ready, the following options are available:

- [Option 1](https://github.com/dtrunk90/wro4jtest/pull/1)
- [Option 2](https://github.com/dtrunk90/wro4jtest/pull/2)

Comment: That is because getDefaultModelFilename(); returns /WEB-INF/wro.xml, while you have the wro.xml in classes folder. Either create a WEB-INF folder in your classpath or do not use getDefaultModelFilename() method.

Comment: No, getDefaultModelFilename() returns wro.xml: https://github.com/alexo/wro4j/blob/1.6.x/wro4j-core/src/main/java/ro/isdc/wro/model/factory/XmlModelFactory.java#L394

Comment: The log says: java.io.IOException: Invalid resource requested: /WEB-INF/wro.xml... That means that the requested file path is: /WEB-INF/wro.xml... which is wrong.

Comment: Right, that means my custom XmlModelFactory doesn't take effect?!

Comment: That seem to be the problem. Do you have the project somewhere on github? I'll try to debug the issue and will let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'll make another minimal project for it to host it on github.